# Android Crashlytics log with useless info, how can I locate the error?

Tags: android, crashlytics, sigabrt

I received this Crashlytics log on Firebase console for my Android app.

I have no idea which module is causing this issue,

From investigation, I collected some info:

- Almost devices are running out of RAM
- It occurs on all brands: Samsung, Oppo, Vivo, ...

Can anyone tell me your approach to locate the error source of this issue?

```
Crashed: Thread :  SIGABRT  0x000027b100003d06
#00 pc 0x7f9a3a070c  
#01 pc 0x7f9a39e544  
#02 pc 0x7f9a359aa4  
#03 pc 0x7f9a354244  
#04 pc 0x7f9a35768c  
#05 pc 0x7f9a3576b0  
#06 pc 0x7f9a3a75d4  
#07 pc 0x7f896c02e0  
#08 pc 0x7f896c941c  
#09 pc 0x13ad881c  
#10 pc 0x7f896c9064  
#11 pc 0x13ee457c  
#12 pc 0x1455087c  
#13 pc 0x70bf21d4  
#14 pc 0x13ad881c  
#15 pc 0x70bf21d4  
#16 pc 0x70da64d4  
#17 pc 0x70b89b3c  
#18 pc 0x7f9a83f464  
#19 pc 0x13ad881c  
#20 pc 0x13ad881c  
#21 pc 0x13ee457c  
#22 pc 0x1455087c  
#23 pc 0x70bf21d4  
#24 pc 0x136c9c1c  
#25 pc 0x73bea754 boot.oat 
#26 pc 0x70bf21d4  
...
```

--- update ---

I did not use proguard:

android/app/build.gradle

```
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
...
android: {
  ...
  buildTypes: {
    ...
    release: {
      minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
      shrinkResources enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that's a native crash, so you can at least narrow it down to anything using C/C++. You might have to debfuscate that, but I'm not sure if Proguard does anything with native crashes.

Comment: Thank @Zoe for pointing out, So I must try Proguard 
 debfuscate?

Comment: As I checked I did not use proguard, as Proguard is for Java code, and the others crash is readable, unreadable crash logs only happen for this kind of crash.,  You right! it's belong to C++ code